# Why not all of the sprites are responding?

Tags: python, pygame

I've been working with pygame documentation game, Chimp Tutorial and i wanted to create more sprites working the same way first one did.

I created 5 sprites:

```
chimp1 = Chimp(speed=9,pos=(10,30))
chimp2 = Chimp(speed=9,pos=(500,180))
chimp3 = Chimp(speed=9,pos=(10,330))
chimp4 = Chimp(speed=9,pos=(1000,480))
chimp5 = Chimp(speed=9,pos=(320,630))
```

I wantend them to work the same way the first one did: rotate when punched;

```
if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    if fist.punch(chimp):
        punch_sound.play()  # punch
        chimp.punched()
```

So I modified provided code following way:

```
for event in pg.event.get():
    if event.type == pg.QUIT:
        going = False
    elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN and event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
        going = False
    elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if fist.punch(chimp1):
            punch_sound.play()  # punch
            chimp1.punched()
        if fist.punch(chimp2):
            punch_sound.play()  # punch
            chimp2.punched()
        if fist.punch(chimp3):
            punch_sound.play()  # punch
            chimp3.punched()
        if fist.punch(chimp4):
            punch_sound.play()  # punch
            chimp4.punched()
        if fist.punch(chimp5):
            punch_sound.play()  # punch
            chimp5.punched()
```

But the result is that only chimp1 is responding to fist.punch().
If i change chimp1 to chimp5, chimp5 is responding and chimp1 not.
What is the reason?
Here is the original code:
https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/chimp.py.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the class `First`:

> ```py
> class Fist(pg.sprite.Sprite):
>    # [...]
>
>    def punch(self, target):
>        """returns true if the fist collides with the target"""
>        if not self.punching:
>            self.punching = True
>            hitbox = self.rect.inflate(-5, -5)
>            return hitbox.colliderect(target.rect)
> ```

You have only 1 `Fist` object instance. As soon as `punch` is called, `self.punching` is set and no other object will respond.

Remove `self.punching = True` from `punch` and put but set it after the click detection:

```py
class Fist(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def punch(self, target):
        """returns true if the fist collides with the target"""
        if not self.punching:
            # self.punching = True                         <--- DELETE 
            hitbox = self.rect.inflate(-5, -5)
            return hitbox.colliderect(target.rect)
```

```py
for event in pg.event.get():
    if event.type == pg.QUIT:
        going = False
    elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN and event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
        going = False
    elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if fist.punch(chimp1):
            punch_sound.play()  # punch
            chimp1.punched()
        if fist.punch(chimp2):
            punch_sound.play()  # punch
            chimp2.punched()
        if fist.punch(chimp3):
            punch_sound.play()  # punch
            chimp3.punched()
        if fist.punch(chimp4):
            punch_sound.play()  # punch
            chimp4.punched()
        if fist.punch(chimp5):
            punch_sound.play()  # punch
            chimp5.punched()
        fist.punching  = True                              # <--- INSERT
```